# value doesent to managed bean in JSF

Tags: jsf

I new to JSF.Try to set outputtext through java.

```xml
    Name
    <h:inputText value="#{customerBean.name}" >         
    </h:inputText>

    JoiningDate
    <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.dateOfBirth}" >
      <f:convertDateTime pattern="d-M-yyyy" />
    </h:outputText>

    <h:commandButton value="View" action="#{customerBean.view}" />
```

In my customer bean iam setting value

```
public void view(){ 
  CustomerDTO dto = new CustomerDTO();
  dto.setName(name);
  dto = dao.view(dto);
  dto.setDateOfBirth(dto.getDateOfBirth()); 
}
```

When i print value of dataOf Birth its print inside view but value not populated in UI?

Comment: What you mean by `not populated in UI`? You're actually sending that value to the managed bean.

Comment: dto.setDateOfBirth(dto.getDateOfBirth()); //impressive!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're concretely asking, but if I'd do a wild guess by solely looking at the source code, I'd say that you actually meant to do `setDateOfBirth(dto.getDateOfBirth());` instead of `dto.setDateOfBirth(dto.getDateOfBirth());`.